# Request Body of IBM Watson Assistant for webhook

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-assistant

I'm creating a bot using IBM Watson Assistant. I am trying to use a webhook, but don't know the format of the POST request JSON/HTML which is sent to the webhook.

My case study is a shop where user can pre-order. I want to send the order details to my back-end server and give the user a reference number for the pre-order. I found nothing in the documentation about what POST request format is sent from IBM Watson Assistant and in what format response should be returned.

I know IBM Watson Assistant does not require a particular response format. It allows the developer to manipulate the response as the developer wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Watson Assistant has a [documented API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs). There are the recommended [V2 Assistant API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2) which can be used to create session and then send messages. The older [V1 Assistant API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1) has more functions and is deeper into the system. Both APIs can be used to write chatbots.

If you mean a [Webhook as the Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks#dialog-webhooks-dialog-node-callout) feature to reach out from a dialog node to an external service, the process is the following:

- in the global configuration, you define the URL and the header
- for a dialog node, you enable webhooks, then define the key / value pairs that are sent as payload. They can differ by dialog node.
- Typically, the expected result is JSON data because it is the easiest to process.

This [IBM Cloud Solution tutorial on building a Slack bot with Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson#load-the-skill-workspace) uses webhooks to call out to a Db2 database. The code is available in a GitHub repo.